# This app is blocked screen after trying to receive steps read data

Tags: google-signin, google-fit

I've been using the google SDK for a while to receive the steps. It was working alright, there was no verification needed and also that screen wasn't shown to the users. From yesterday I got `This app is blocked` screen for new google accounts.

Im using two datatypes:

```
DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA - FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ
DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA - FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ
```

Im using GoogleSignInAccount/GoogleSignIn to sign via OAuth. Do I need to verify the app to proceed?